# Math equation to use as an expression

Tags: c#, math, equation

I'm fairly new here and started out with programming quite recently. Lots of fun!

EDIT:
Anyway, I'm in need of a piece of code in C# that can do the following I will describe below.

Let's see if I can put this right:

I have `"x"` amount of `"ingredients"` that I want to mix.

There can only be mixed a total of `"y"` ingredients together. (Meaning `if y=3`, I can only make a salad with **MAXIMUM** three ingredients (Less ingredients is ok.), even if I have more ingredients available.)

Ok, here's my problem; I want to know **how many UNIQUE dishes** that can possibly be made out of the amount of `ingredients (x)`, when `y=whatever`.

Lets call the ingredients A,B,C,D... etc.

So, again `if y=3 and x=4 (A,B,C,D)`, unique dishes would e.g be:

```
A
AD
ABB
DBA
etc...
```

However, the dishes `DBA` and `ADB`, for example, would consist of the same amount of equal ingredients and basically be the same dish, and therefore only be counted ONE time.

Hope I could explain myself somewhat correct.

Thanks!

Comment: there is a math.stackexchange.com for mathematics questions, but the math term you're looking for is "combinations" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

Comment: This is a question about combinatorics (n-choose-k) and is off topic here. Sorry. Try the wikipedia article.

Comment: This online tool gives you the algebraic forumlae. After that it becomes programming problem. http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html  Maybe you could write some code & show it to us?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about "pure math", and would be better suited on math.stackexchange.com, once it meets their quality standards.

Comment: There is [another stack exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com) that focus on math.

Comment: Pure math questions should be asked on http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I ment math.stackexchange.com, not mathematica, sorry.

Comment: Choosing i items from a total of x, without regard to the order, but with repeating elements, can be formulated as “x+i-1 choose i”. Sum for all possible i from 1 to y and you obtain [this formula](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7NMmk.png) with the help of [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28%28x%2bi-1%29%20choose%20i%29%20for%20i%20from%201%20to%20y).

Comment: If you'll edit your question to specify that you're looking for programs to compute this, I can give you one. (I wrote a C# one since you tagged this C#, but now the question is on hold.)

Comment: Ok, then I will take my question there instead.. Or look into combinations, and try to figure it out. Thanks for your answers and sorry to bother.

Answer (score 1):

Although the best place to get this answer is from a math forum, here is an attempt...

The question can be answered using combinatorial math, in particular, this one is a ratio of factorials, referred to as a *binomial coefficient*:

***Given***: (EDITED for no repetitions)
x = total available ingredients
y = max ingredients/dish
***Then, the  number of possible dishes*** each using three ingredients is given by: ***x!/y!(x-y)!***
***For example***, say:
x = 10
y = 3
Then:
10!/3!(10-3)! = 3628800/(6*5040) = 120 possible dishes

***[HERE](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)*** is a link that may help with other combinatorial algorithms.  (search for binomial coefficient)

Comment: You are counting dishes which only differ in the order of their ingredients. Question states that these should be counted only once.

Comment: @MvG I will make an adjustment.

Comment: Oh, nice! I asked the question again on a math-forum, but this seems to do just what I'm after. Thank you!

Comment: On second thought, it's actually not completely working, since it's not taking in consideration that a dish can consist of less than, in your example, three ingredients..

Comment: @user3412636 - this equation can easily handle a differing number of ingredients by simply exchanging in numbers as needed.  If you want the number of possibilities using only 2 ingredients out of a possible 10 for example, it would be 10!/2!*(10-2)!  In this way it is infinitely flexible.  However, it is not omniscient with respect to reading minds. :)

Comment: Oh, I think you misunderstood what I meant. Typical forum-problems. I was trying with 4 ingredients in 3 places, which with this formula would give an answer of 4. ABC, ABD, ACD and BCD. What I mean is that a dish also could be e.g. A, AB, BD. But you're right, I missed one point. I also want it to be able for a dish to be e.g. AA, ABB, DDD. Meaning x is not the amount of ingredients, but types of ingredients. Getting much here. Maybe better try again in the math-section. But thanks for your efforts!